# Spark pairedrdd: foldByKey usage

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a question about using foldByKey on pairedRDD. Here is my sample data:

```
val data: Array[(String, Array[Int])] = Array((120,Array(10, 4, 108, 520)), (2,Array(25, 11, 270, 180, 14)))
```

I would like to have data in the following way:

```
val data: Array[(String, String)] = Array((120, "10 4 108 520"), (2, "25 11 270 180 14"))
```

I think foldByKey would be the function to use, any help on how to use that to convert my array of ints to string would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since your data is already stored in an Array, you just need a `mapValues` call:

```
data.mapValues(_.mkString(" "))
```

However, if your arrays are too big, and you actually have it stored as:

```
120 | 10
120 | 4
120 | 108
etc
```

Then you'll want to use `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey`...depending on whether order needs to be maintained as it turns into a string.

Comment: I would say that `groupByKey` + `mapValues` is a much better choice than `reduceByKey`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val data: Array[(String, Array[Int])] = Array(("120",Array(10, 4, 108, 520)), ("2",Array(25, 11, 270, 180, 14)))
val d=data.map(x=>(x._1,x._2.mkString(" ")))
val e=sc.parallelize(d)
e.foldByKey("")(_+_).collect
```

Correct me if this is not straight forward.